# Spring boot 2 + log detail logs do not work, with Logback, Hibernate + Weblogic

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, oracle11g, logback, weblogic12c

I use **oracle 11.x**, **Spring boot 2.x** , **maven**, **weblogic** – as  external server.

- The entry point

```java
@SpringBootConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebSpringBootJarApplication
        extends SpringBootServletInitializer
        implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER  = LoggerFactory.getLogger( WebSpringBootJarApplication.class );

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebSpringBootJarApplication.class, args);
        LOGGER.info("Start an application...");
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        LOGGER.info("There is building the web application!");
        return builder.sources(WebSpringBootJarApplication.class);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.main.banner-mode=off

####################################################
#                    Oracle 11x
####################################################
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver


logging.config=classpath:logger/logback-spring.xml

logging.file.dir=logs
logging.file.name.var=log.log

logging.file.archive.format.name=program_.%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.log
```

logback-spring.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="10 seconds" >

    <include resource="logger/settingslogger/defaults-spring.xml"/>


   <springProfile name="default">

        <include resource="logger/consolelogger/console-appender-spring.xml"/>

        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </root>

    </springProfile>


    <springProfile name="production">

        <include resource="logger/productionappenderlogger/logback-appender-production-spring.xml"/>

        <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="org.springframework.data" level="DEBUG">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </logger>


        <logger name="weblogic.war.spring.boot" level="ERROR">

            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>

        </logger>

        <logger name="weblogic.war.spring.boot" level="INFO">

            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>

        </logger>

        <logger name="weblogic.war.spring.boot" level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="weblogic.war.spring.boot" level="INFO">

            <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>

        </logger>

    </springProfile>


</configuration>
```

When the postman is sending a request, that I have the response:

> {
>       "timestamp": "2020-03-05T13:47:37.128+0000",
>       "status": 500,
>       "error": "Internal Server Error",
>       "message": "JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is weblogic.transaction.RollbackException: setRollbackOnly called on transaction",
>       "path": "/sat/api/save/differentTypes"
>   }

And the console I see this:

> 05-03-2020 16:47:37.095  DEBUG  10500     [ (self-tuning)']  m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor  :  Read "application/json;charset=UTF-8" to [weblogic.war.spring.boot.service.dto.differenttypes.DifferentTypesDtoEightProduce@f8bde55f
>   Different (truncated)...]
>     05-03-2020 16:47:37.124  DEBUG  10500     [ (self-tuning)']  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet         :  Failed to complete request: org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is weblogic.transaction.RollbackException: setRollbackOnly called on transaction

**Update**

I tried to add follows tthe settings into logback-spring.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="10 seconds">

    <include resource="logger/default/defaults-spring.xml"/>

    <springProfile name="default">

        <include resource="logger/console/console-appender-spring.xml"/>

        <root level="TRACE">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </root>

    </springProfile>

    <springProfile name="dev">

          <include resource="logger/console/console-appender-spring.xml"/>

           <include resource="logger/production/logback-appender-production-spring.xml"/>

        <!-- <root level="INFO">
             <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
         </root>-->

        <logger name="ch.qos.logback" level="DEBUG" additivity="true">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG" additivity="true" >
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="org.springframework.data" level="TRACE" additivity="true">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="org.springframework.data.jpa" level="TRACE" additivity="true">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="org.hibernate" level="TRACE" additivity="true">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="org.hibernate.validator" level="TRACE" additivity="true">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="org.hibernate.sql" level="TRACE" additivity="true">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql" level="TRACE" additivity="true">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder" level="TRACE" additivity="true">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils" level="TRACE" additivity="true">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreator" level="TRACE" additivity="true">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="com.dao" level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="com.service" level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="com.web" level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </logger>

          <logger name="ch.qos.logback" level="DEBUG">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="org.springframework.data" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="org.springframework.data.jpa" level="DEBUG" additivity="false" >
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
        </logger>


        <logger name="org.hibernate" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="org.hibernate.validator" level="WARN">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="org.hibernate.sql" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreator" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="com.dao" level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="com.service" level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="com.web" level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
        </logger>

      <!--  http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html-->
        <contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
            <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
        </contextListener>

    </springProfile>
</configuration>
```

```
spring.profiles.active=dev

logging.config=classpath:logger/logback-spring.xml

logging.file.dir=logs_gov
logging.file.name.var=gov_new.log
logging.file.archive.format.name=gov_new.%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.log
```

- weblogic.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
        xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        https://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd
        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
        https://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.9/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

    <wls:context-root>sun</wls:context-root>

    <wls:container-descriptor>

           <wls:prefer-application-packages>
               <wls:package-name>ch.qos.logback.*</wls:package-name>
               <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
            </wls:prefer-application-packages>

    <!--    <wls:prefer-application-resources>
            <wls:resource-name>ch/qos/logback/core/ConsoleAppender.class</wls:resource-name>
            <wls:resource-name>ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/RollingFileAppender.class</wls:resource-name>
            <wls:resource-name>ch/qos/logback/classic/encoder/PatternLayoutEncoder.class</wls:resource-name>
            <wls:resource-name>ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/TimeBasedRollingPolicy.class</wls:resource-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-resources>-->

    </wls:container-descriptor>

</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

**I don't see errors in console when occur an transaction rollback.**

> 12-03-2020 14:21:25.756  INFO 7216   c.w.r.s.d.DifferentTypesSaveRest 
>   : Writed object : DifferentTypesDtoEightProduce{status=OPEN}
>   DifferentTypesDtoFour{year=2020, car=true}
>   com.service.dto.differenttypes.DifferentTypesDtoEightProduce@64e50443
>   DifferentTypesDtoTwo{id=135, name='fan5'}
>   DifferentTypesDtoSix{cost=10.0, character=W}   12-03-2020 14:21:25.759
>   DEBUG 7216   m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Using
>   'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json] 
>   12-03-2020 14:21:25.774 DEBUG 7216
>   m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Writing
>   [DifferentTypesDtoEightProduce{status=OPEN}
>   DifferentTypesDtoFour{year=2020, car=true} com.service.dt
>   (truncated)...]  12-03-2020 14:21:25.781 DEBUG 7216
>   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK 
>   12-03-2020 14:23:13.766 DEBUG 7216   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
>   : POST "/sun/api/save/differentTypes", parameters={}  12-03-2020
>   14:23:13.766 DEBUG 7216   s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping :
>   Mapped to
>   com.web.rest.save.differentTypes.DifferentTypesSaveRest#setDifferentTypes(DifferentTypesDtoEightProduce)
>   12-03-2020 14:23:13.767 DEBUG 7216
>   m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Read
>   "application/json;charset=UTF-8" to
>   [DifferentTypesDtoEightProduce{status=OPEN}
>   DifferentTypesDtoFour{year=2020, car=true} com.service.dt
>   (truncated)...]  12-03-2020 14:23:13.804 DEBUG 7216
>   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete request:
>   org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA
>   transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested
>   exception is weblogic.transaction.RollbackException: setRollbackOnly
>   called on transaction  12-03-2020 14:23:13.811 DEBUG 7216
>   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "FORWARD" dispatch for POST
>   "/sun/error", parameters={}  12-03-2020 14:23:13.812 DEBUG 7216
>   s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
>   12-03-2020 14:23:13.820 DEBUG 7216
>   o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json',
>   given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json,
>   application/json, application/*+json]  12-03-2020 14:23:13.820 DEBUG
>   7216   o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing
>   [{timestamp=Thu Mar 12 14:23:13 MSK 2020, status=500, error=Internal
>   Server Error, message=JTA transa (truncated)...]  12-03-2020
>   14:23:13.824 DEBUG 7216   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        :
>   Exiting from "FORWARD" dispatch, status 500

How can I configure detailed error output into a console and a file, when the errors appears during work  **Hibernate**, when **Hibernate** is throwing exceptions with database…

How can also I configure when values that should be written to the database are already inserted in instance **PreparedStatement**

Answer (score 1):

try adding the following lines to your weblogic.xml:

```
<wls:prefer-application-resources>
    <wls:resource-name>org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class</wls:resource-name>
</wls:prefer-application-resources>
```

Also this line would not be necessary:

```
<wls:package-name>ch.qos.logback.*</wls:package-name>
```

because logback is an implementation of sl4j that you are already including it